# Can any language be used with Hadoop framework?

Tags: java, php, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Apart from Java, Ruby (that I know), can other programming language be used with Hadoop framework? Like PHP, .net? Or anything else?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8574485/2055998

Answer (score 0):

Any Language that deals with standard input and standard output can be used for writing Map Reduce jobs of Hadoop framework

Comment: Yup. I just figure it out. Thanks!